# Accessing objects and its properties inside an array of objects in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, object

I am new coding in Objective-C and I am trying to figure out how to do the following:

I have a class `Company`:

```
@interface Company : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *companyID;

@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *companyName;

@end
```

I am getting a dictionary from a server and just parsing in objects.
After that, I am adding these objects in an array (It´s working - no problem here - I got the JSON).

```
NSMutableDictionary *companyDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:response];

NSArray *companyArray = [companyDictionary valueForKey:@"data"];
NSMutableArray *companyInformationArray = [NSMutableArray new];

//Parser
for (int i = 0; i < [companyArray count]; i++) {
    Company *company = [Company new];
    company.companyID = [[companyArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"company_id"];
    company.companyName = [[companyArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"];

    [companyInformationArray addObject:company];
}
```

THE PROBLEM IS: I need to access the objects and its fields inside

```
companyInformationArray
```

I am just trying to do something similar with (these two approaching will not work of course):

```
Company *company = [Company new];
company = [[companyInformationArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Or:

```
Company *company = [Company new];
company.companyName = [[companyInformationArray objectAtIndex:0] companyName];
```

Could you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: A very minor, unrelated observation: It's often prudent to use `copy` rather than `strong` for your `NSString` properties of classes like `Company`. By using `strong`, if the string happened to be a `NSMutableString` and it was mutated later, you risk having your `Company` object unintentionally mutate, too. By making it `copy`, you avoid this (admittedly edge-case) scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the top of my head (not running it to test)...

```
// get the Company object at slot [0] in the array of Company objects
Company *company = (Company *)[companyInformationArray objectAtIndex:0];

// now use the properties...
myNameLabel.text = company.companyName;
myIDLabel.text = company.companyID;
```

Answer (score 6):

Objective-C now supports lightweight generics. For example, rather than a simple `NSMutableArray`, you can specify that your array is an array of `Company` objects:

```
NSMutableArray <Company *> *companyInformationArray;
```

Then you can do something like:

```
NSString *nameOfSecondCompany = companyInformationArray[1].companyName;
```

The virtue of this is that the compiler will warn you if you try to add something that isn't a `Company` and likewise you enjoy strong typing of the properties without any casting.

Comment: Thank you for helping as well. 
I will keep it in mind.

Comment: Nice addition; this is especially useful when Xcode auto-completes enumeration blocks, e.g. instead of `[companyInformationArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop){}];`, you get `[companyInformationArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Company * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop){}];`

Comment: This is a much better option than casting the element at a particular index. Why forego compiler support if you have it?